Can the double-slit experiment be explained as a limitation of the measuring apparatus?
Noob here. I'm struggling with the idea that the wave function collapse upon observation in the double-slit experiment is merely due to a limitation in our measuring apparatus.
To draw an analogy, imagine detecting invisible trucks by their impact on walls that stop them. We might conclude that the trucks move when unobserved but stop once we observe them.
In the context of the double-slit experiment, rather than representing a true forward movement, the act of measurement might restrict the wave-like behavior over an area, channeling it into a particle-like behavior. If we could observe the phenomenon without interacting with it (including via electric field indirectly), might we then see it retaining its wave properties? In essence, is it possible that what we interpret as a particle property is actually a "restricted" wave due to the limitations of our measurement techniques? This would not be counter intuitive, so I am sure I am missing something.
Please point me to experiments that have ruled this out. I have read similar questions but looking for a satisfactory answer.
Thank you in advance =)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

the photon is a local wave in the em field ... it always has wave properties. The em field guides all interactions. The photon/truck is dumb.

This might help - Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?

Thank you @mmesser314
